# iOS Box SDK BoxFolder.children always nil

Tags: ios, box-api

I can get the folder_id by using [Box createFolderWithName:]. But when I try to use the folder_id to get its children, it does not work. Here's my code:

```
[Box createFolderWithName:@"My APP" parentFolderID:[Box rootFolderID] share:NO callbacks:^(id<BoxOperationCallbacks>on){

    on.userInfo (^(NSDictionary* result) {
        // do something with the return value (typically stored with key @"results") of the operation

        NSNumber *appFolderId = [result objectForKey:@"folder_id"];
        BoxFolder *appFolder = [Box folderWithID:appFolderId];
        [appFolder updateWithCallbacks:^(id<BoxOperationCallbacks>on){
            on.after(^(BoxCallbackResponse response) {
                if (response == BoxCallbackResponseSuccessful) {
                    NSLog(@"Folder updated. Children count is: %d", [appFolder.children count]);
                    // Send a notification, call a delegate, use KVO use locally or whatever to use the children.
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"Folder not updated.");
                }
            });


        }];


    });

}];
```

children is always nil. I also tried with [Box rootFolder] but same result.

Can anyone help me with it? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you are getting a valid folder id, I wonder if you now have to update the content information via a call to updateWithCallbacks:.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to use updateWithCallbacks but it crashes. Do you have a snippet of code that I can take a look at how to get the children of a folder? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm confused about something. If you just created the "My App" folder, why would you expect anything in it. Instead you should be using the parent folder with your updateWithCallbacks method. Also, the call crashes because the folder object returned by folderWithID: is corrupted. (That story would lead to a question to Box of why the Box class can contain multiple copies of a BoxID that point to different objects.)

Comment: I'm trying to create some sub-folders under the "My App" folder. Besides, if "My App" folder is already created, it will still return the folder id (same as search for the folder).

Comment: Nothing in your code sample represents that. Anyway, in my experiment, the way I received an uncorrupted reference to the new folder after it is created, was to first call updateWithCallbacks: with the parent folder and then fetch the new folder from the parents children arrow.

Comment: Thanks. Using updateWithCallbacks: with the parent folder solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following sample may help.

```
if (appFolder.isFolder) {
        [appFolder updateWithCallbacks:^(id<BoxOperationCallbacks> on) {
            on.after(^(BoxCallbackResponse response) {
                if (response == BoxCallbackResponseSuccessful) {
                    NSLog(@"Folder updated. Children count is: %d", [appFolder.children count]);
                    // Send a notification, call a delegate, use KVO use locally or whatever to use the children.
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"Folder not updated.");
                }
            });
        }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"NOT WORKING WITH A FOLDER!");
    }
```

Comment: I tired but it crashes at [BoxURLFactory urlForGetAccountTreeForFolderID:] exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. Seems that using BoxFolder *appFolder = [Box folderWithID:appFolderId] did not create the url for it.

Comment: I suggest that you share your code. I haven't used the search query so may not have input for you.

Comment: Please see the updated question. I'm using createFolderWithName to get the folderId.